# Rapidly cycling text with javascript and random pauses / timeouts

Tags: javascript, text, timeout

I came across a really good effect for flashing up words using javascript that has random pauses where the script stops running on a particular phrase and then restarts again. This effect can be viewed at http://mmmatt.com/about

I have looked at the source for this website but I cannot seem to get the javascript to work on my own website - I think it is because the script on the website above is triggered by clicking on a link on the home page - I simply want the script to apply to an`<h1>`element and to start running on document load. My javascript skills are very poor to say the least so any help in allowing me to modify the js and html markup below to get this running will be gratefully received.

The js for the website is:

```
/**
* Site!
*/
var Site = Site || { };

$(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
$(document).trigger('Matt');
}, 500);
});
/**
* About
*/
Site.About = function() {

self = {

$el : { },

data :{
  'count' : 0,
  'loop'  : null
},

cycle : function() {

  clearTimeout(self.data.loop);
  var shit = Math.floor(Math.random() * self.data.count);
  var timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 30;
  var chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
  self.$el.doin.find('.active').removeClass('active');
  self.$el.doin.find('span').eq(shit).addClass('active');

  if ( chance == 0 ) timeout = 1500;
  self.data.loop = setTimeout(self.cycle, timeout);

},

load : function() {
  clearTimeout(self.data.loop);
  setTimeout(function() {
      self.$el.doin = $('#project .doin');
      self.data.count = self.$el.doin.find('span').length;
      self.cycle();
  }, 1000);
},

unload : function() {
  clearTimeout(self.data.loop);
}

};

return {
load   : self.load,
unload : self.unload
}

}();
```

The html is:

```
<div id="clone" class="project"></div>
<div id="project" class="project" data-section="about">

<div class="aboutContainer">
<div class="doin">
  Matthew Miller is<br/>
                <span class="active">walking in circles</span>
                  <span >trying too hard</span>
                  <span >not trying hard enough</span>
                  <span >dancing</span>
                  <span >making strange noises</span>
                  <span >eating a donut</span>
                  <span >moving extremely fast</span>
                  <span >sitting still</span>
                  <span >making dinner</span>
                  <span >naked</span>
                  <span >making cookies</span>
                  <span >in love</span>
                  <span >doing the same thing</span>
                  <span >disappointed in pablo</span>
                  <span >skateboarding with steven</span>
                  <span >walking millie</span>
                  <span >in his favorite place</span>
                  <span >still alive</span>
                  <span >drinking water</span>
                  <span >running around naked</span>
                  <span >drawing</span>
                  <span >sleeping</span>
                  <span >a doctor</span>
                  <span >telling the truth</span>
```

etc.etc.

The only relevant css I can find is:

```
.aboutContainer .doin span {
display:none
}
.aboutContainer .doin span.active {
display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the same effect with much less code:

```
function display() {
  var el= document.querySelectorAll('.doin span'),
      rnd= Math.floor(Math.random() * el.length-1) + 1,
      rnd2= Math.round(Math.random()*20);

  document.querySelector('.doin span.active').className= '';
  el[rnd].className= 'active';
  if(rnd2===5) {
    setTimeout(display, 1500);
  } else {
    setTimeout(display, 100);
  }
} //display
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k50rdxjp/1)

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so quickly. Your script is just what I needed. You have no idea how many hours I spent yesterday trying to figure this out! Very grateful.